# How can I reduce the spark tasks when I run a spark job

Tags: apache-spark, merge, apache-spark-sql-repartition

Here is my spark job stages:
[image]

It has 260000 tasks because the job rely on more then 200000 small hdfs files, each file about
50MB and it is stored in gzip format

I tried using the following settings to reduce the tasks but it didn't work.

```
...
--conf spark.sql.mergeSmallFileSize=10485760 \
--conf spark.hadoopRDD.targetBytesInPartition=134217728 \
--conf spark.hadoopRDD.targetBytesInPartitionInMerge=134217728 \
...
```

Is it because file format is gzip that made it cannot be merged?

How can I do now if I want to reduce the job tasks?

Comment: This is classic small file problem, Either repartitioning your data to less number of partitions, or using adaptive framework `spark.sql.adaptive.enabled true` should work